# No module named pip when installing Folium in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, folium

I am trying to import folium in my jupyter notebook and it gives me:

C:\Users\El7md\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe: No module named pip

This is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
!py -m pip install folium
```

I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Make a new cell above the one you are showing in your post, and put the following in it:

```py
%pip install folium
```

(If you happen to be using Anaconda/conda anywhere replace what I am suggesting above with `%conda install -c conda-forge folium`.)
Run that cell and then restart the kernel.

Now delete the line `!py -m pip install folium` from the code you posted and replace it with `import folium`. Run the code block in the Jupyter cell and see if the `import folium` throws an error.